# execCommand without a selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, execcommand

I have the following div:

```
<div contenteditable="true" unselectable="off" id="foo">
```

inside this div I want to make a specific amount of words look **bold** everytime a user makes an input. Therefor I have the following changelistener:

```
$('#foo').live('focus', function() {
   before = $(this).html();
}).live('blur keyup paste', function() { 
   if (before != $(this).html()) { $(this).trigger('change'); }
});

$('#foo').live('change', function() {
   // make certain words bold
   document.execCommand ('bold', false, null); // doesn't work
});
```

I tried to use the *document.execCommand()* but it only works when I select the text which I want to make **bold**. But I don't want to select the text because the user doesn't know the words which should be **bold**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use execCommand to bold text without selecting it first.

I don't understand what are you doing exactly, but if you know the words you want to make bold, just replace them with `<strong>your word</strong>` in the editors html, using js.

Comment: which disables undo/redo, in my test.